# Do I need to kill all sprites before switching states in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

Do I need to kill all sprites and animations before I switch from state A to state B in Phaser, or does Phaser clean them up automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Kamen Minkov's answer is almost right but the argument you need to consider is `clearWorld`.

If you set it to false, all your objects will remain there when you switch state, a bit like if you had set up both states at the same time. Otherwise, the default behavior is indeed to destroy all of your game objects when switching states.

`clearCache` is about clearing the preloaded assets (meaning you'll have to preload them again). Most of the time you'll want to leave it to false, unless for instance you've preloaded large amounts of assets for a cinematic and you don't need them anymore ; in that case removing them from the cache is probably a good idea to free up some memory.

Comment: What you are saying is what I understand from other blog posts. But even with this.state.start('SlideShow',true,false) I keep seeing the previous state sprites below my new state objects on screen. Things are not going away.

Comment: @omarojo : The default behavior is to destroy everything between states, so if that's what you want "this.state.start('SlideShow')" should suffice. Since it's not the case there must be something wrong with your code, like maybe you're not creating objects from within the scene?

Check the official examples maybe (https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/tree/master/projects) to compare the scene mgmt code with yours.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `clearCache` bool parameter for `Phaser.StateManager.start()` (the third one), so you most probably don't need to do anything manually.

[API Docs for StateManager](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.StateManager.html#start)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's the cache that contains your sprites and animations, so if you want to clear the cache after your Game state, you may do so like this: `game.state.start("Menu", true, true)`

Comment: what happens if i don't remove my cache? will it lead to memory leak issue or gradual game slow down??

Comment: There is some garbage collection happening, but I wouldn't rely on it too much if it's about a lot of assets. I doubt a memory leak would happen unless there's a bug somewhere, and as for game slowdown - from my experience it's what's being rendered to the screen that can slow the game down, not what's loaded in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Kill doesn't really mean clean up as in memory clean up. It has nothing to do with removing a sprite from the game, it is just declaring a sprite to be killed and removing it from view. I believe Phaser actually handles the clean up for you automatically when you switch in between states.

Comment: so you are saying that i don't need to bother about memory leak issues that occur due to sprites while switching states?

Answer (score 0):

You should free the memory used by your game state on the `shutodown` method, which is automatically called by Phaser when changing states.

Example:

```js
MyState.prototype.shutdown = function () 
{
     this.background.destroy();    //Phaser.Image
     this.mySprite.destroy(true);  //Phaser.Sprite
     this.myImage.destroy(true);   //Phaser.Image
     this.game.cache.removeImage("image-I-wont-use-anymore", true);
};
```